# Unable to connect with RDS MySql Working fine with XAMPP local server, But not connecting on cPanel server

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-rds

Unable to connect with RDS MySql Working fine with XAMPP local server, But not connecting on cPanel server
Here is PHP code:

```
mysql_connect("MyDb.czbeqpr93eiy.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306","MyDb","MyDbPwd");
mysql_select_db("MyDb");
```

Comment: you are using deprecated function. Please try new mySqLi functions.

Comment: but its working on XAMPP local server